# Updating Ubuntu and not removing software!

Tags: software-installation, upgrade

I have a lot of software on the operating system, and now Ubuntu update is delivering version 19.

How can I upgrade the operating system without removing the software and having to reinstall the software on the operating system?

Comment: An upgrade will not remove your installed software. It will only remove packages which are obsoleted and replaced.

Comment: I mean the upgrade from version 18 to version 19.
Would not this be erased?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18, or Ubuntu 19.  There are Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Ubuntu 18.10, Ubuntu Core 18, Ubuntu 19.04 etc... Ubuntu Core has only a single release per year hence is *yy* in format, where as the main releases are *yy.mm* in format. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (commonly shrunk to 18) will upgrade to the next LTS release (20.04 LTS when out in 2020) or to 18.10, but is untested direct to 19.04.  Do you mean 18.10?  `do-release-upgrade` & upgrade tools perform as Jos has stated, or you can use 'something-else' on install media (and not selecting format; but this applies to Ubuntu repo software only)

Comment: No, not in principle. Packages are downloaded from the repos and copied over your existing files. Your settings and data won't be affected. Some third-party package sources, however, are disabled during the upgrade. After the reboot, you will need to go into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and re-enable them. But it is rare that a package stops functioning completely after an upgrade.

Comment: Nothing gets 'erased'. Many packages get *replaced*. Whether or not your software gets removed depends upon it's dependencies, if any.

Comment: You're all partially incorrect. Packages **may** get removed during a dist upgrade, if you answer "y" to the question "remove software". And in my particular case, it removed `ukuu` and `jNetMap` *probably* unnecessarily.  `jNetMap` is just a network map/pinging python app. Newer versions (19.00+) of `ukuu` are now paid apps, but older versions (18.XX) could have been left alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not remove your software it will only upgrade your base system and some of the packages that are available in the repo. if any that do get removed will be old system packages and dependencies that most likely replaced by alternatives. you can back up your system. in conclusion, Ubuntu will not delete any packages and software and settings don't worry. back up is the only way